# How do i make "if" statement in C programming?

Tags: c

I wrote my first if statement in C, can you tell me what's wrong with my code?. When I compile and run, at first it runs and shows the "Select statement (1/2) : ", but when I input 1 or 2, the program finished running with "return value 3221225477" [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cgaq.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int end;
    char b = "Statement 1";
    char c = "Statement 2";

    printf("Select statement (1/2) : ");
    scanf("%i", a);

    if (a == 1) {
        printf("%c \n", b);
    } else {
        if (a == 2) {
            printf("%c \n", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `scanf("%i", a);` statement is wrong. You need to pass the *address* of the target variable: `scanf("%i", &a);`. After that wrong call, all bets are off. And your `char b...` and `char c...` declarations are badly wrong. You need arrays of `char` to hold multi-character strings.

Comment: When you compile, set the "show all warnings" option (`-Wall` for gcc). The compiler would have warned you about most mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. If you take the `if` block out of the code, and unconditionally `printf` one of the variable values instead, do you still have the problem? Given that, do you believe the question is actually about how to "make an if statement"? I can see between two and five things wrong with the code, depending how you count. The `if` syntax is *not one of them*.

Comment: `char b = "Statement 1";` should be `char *b = "Statement 1";` — and similarly for `c`.  The formats should use `%s` instead of `%c` when printing `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
char c = "Statement 2";
```

But `"Statement 2"` is a string literal, and not a `char`, and should be printed with a `%s` specifier, and not `%c`. This is why you are getting unexpected behavior.

Please also note that `end` is unused, and your nested `if` can be streamlined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    char *b = "Statement 1";
    char *c = "Statement 2";

    printf("Select statement (1/2) : ");
    scanf("%i", &a);

    if (a == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", b);
    } 
    else if (a == 2) {
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, since `a` is a numeric type, we can use a `switch` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    char *b = "Statement 1";
    char *c = "Statement 2";

    printf("Select statement (1/2) : ");
    scanf("%i", a);

    switch (a) {
        case 1:
        printf("%s\n", b);
        break;

        case 2:
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when I run it :

Select statement (1/2) : 1

--------------------------------
Process exited after 8.864 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Oops. I was passing `a` to scanf rather than the address of `a`. Edited.